# Configuring eth0 and eth1 on PowerEdge 2900 assigns both to same adapter

Tags: linux-networking

I have the following in my /etc/network/interfaces file

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
address xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
netmask xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
gateway xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx

auto eth1
iface eth1 inet static
address xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
netmask xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
gateway xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
```

On reboot the server is not configuring both interfaces then I did a ifconfig and noticed that both eth0 and eth1 have the same MAC address. So it seems like both interfaces are being assigned to the same NIC. I have 2 Nics in the server. Can anyone help me whats going on

Comment: Are you certain they both have the exact same mac address?  Many interfaces built into servers are only different by a single bit.

Comment: What is the output of `ifconfig` ?

Answer (score 1):

Find out other NIC MAC address and place it in `/etc/network/interfaces`

In CentOS I could determine information about network devices in:

```
/etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules
```

I think `hwinfo` command might help too.

Comment: How do you place the MAC address in the interfaces file?

Comment: e.g. under `gateway xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx` add `hwaddress ether 01:02:03:04:05:06`

Comment: If you just delete or rename the above file, it will get regenerated after reboot.